# SQL Query to return rows with the most columns populated

Tags: sql-server, string, count, sql-order-by, unpivot

Azure SQL Server 2019.

We have a table `Table1` with over 100 columns of differing types of `nvarchar` data, all of which are allowed `NULL` values, and where there could be anywhere from 1 to 100 columns populated in a given record.  I need to formulate a query that returns the rows ranked by how many columns have values in them, in descending order.

I started going down a road of using `DATALENGTH` and having to type out the name of every single column, but I can only imagine there has to be a more efficient way.  Assuming the column names are `column1`, `column2`, `column3` etc, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Not a sql server exprt (yet!) but couldn't you query sys.columns ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You could pivot the table so you have 100+ individual rows for each key and count the non-null values and group by the PK.

Comment: @Manakin thanks for the link, I am definitely not an expert either!

Comment: @Tony that's a great suggestion.  Let me look into that.

Comment: If performance is not a priority then you can try to compose the query using dynamic sql query. Unpivoting will still require you to list all the 100 columns manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a lateral join that unpivots the columns to rows? This requires enumerating the columns just once, like so:

```
select t.*, c.cnt
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select count(*) cnt
    from (values (t.column1), (t.column2), (t.column3)) x(col)
    where col is not null
) c
order by c.cnt desc
```